# Likelihood problem. compute MLE

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference

[image]

I wanted to ask you an opinion about this exercise. I don't understand how compute sufficient statistic in this case important point, to compute the log and derivate and find my MLE.

Comment: It might help to note that $f_{\theta}$ is a gamma pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\prod_i f_\theta(X_i) = (\theta^3/2)^n \exp\left\{2 \sum_i \log X_i -\theta \sum_i X_i\right\}.$$
From here, can you guess what a sufficient statistic would be? Think about the Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem, for example.

---

The log likelihood is then
$$n \log(\theta^3 / 2) + 2 \sum_i \log X_i - \theta \sum_i X_i$$
The derivative with respect to $\theta$ is
$$\frac{3n}{\theta} - \sum_i X_i.$$
Setting it to zero will give you your MLE for $\theta$ and $3/\theta$.